# price of single product in bundle

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, price, magento-community, bundled-product

I have a bundle with a fixed price. If I add this bundle to the cart, the entry in the database looks somethink like this:

```
| item_id  |  product_type  |  parent_item_id  |  sku      |  price  |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1        |  bundle        |                  |  bundle1  |   49.99 |
| 2        |  simple        |  1               |  p1       |   0     |
| 3        |  simple        |  1               |  p2       |   0     |
| 4        |  simple        |  1               |  p2       |   0     |
```

but I'm actually need a price for every single product based on the percentage share from the original price to the bundle and the bundle price should be 0.

The way I would go is to rewrite the class `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price` and do the calculation by my own. Maybe I could use some events and don't need to rewrite the class which definitely would be better.

Actually I'm a bit worried about the price rounding. I think in some case the total of all simple product prices could be diffrent to the actual fixed bundle price.

So thats why I would like to ask you if you know a core method to do this which I don't think of. Or maybe there is already a existing module which does exactly this calculation.

Comment: I once wasted hundreds of hours in this rabbit hole, can't recommend it.